# count the number of occurrences of labels in each cluster

Tags: r, performance

I have the output from the clustering algorithm as a vector with cluster numbers from 0 to n

```
set.seed(1)
cluster <- sample(0:5, 100, replace = T)
cluster
  [1] 0 3 0 1 4 2 5 1 2 2 0 4 4 1 5 5 1 0 4 4 0 0 5 4 4 1 1 5 0 3 0 3 2 5 1 1 5 3 3
 [40] 3 1 3 0 5 0 3 0 5 1 2 1 5 5 1 4 1 5 5 5 0 2 2 5 3 5 2 0 3 4 0 0 5 3 4 4 3 5 4
 [79] 3 3 0 4 4 5 0 0 2 5 1 1 2 5 1 3 2 4 1 1 0 2
```

there is also a vector with labels 0 and 1

```
label <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
label
  [1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
 [40] 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
 [79] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of labels in each cluster except cluster 0, also calculate the percentage and sort the rows accordingly.
Something like that.

```
cluster_metrics(cluster,label)
     clust sum_1 sum_0   percent
[1,]     2     7     5 0.5833333
[2,]     4     8     7 0.5333333
[3,]     1     9     9 0.5000000
[4,]     5    10    11 0.4761905
[5,]     3     7     8 0.4666667
```

---

I wrote a function for this

```
cluster_metrics <- function(clust, label){
  mx <-  max(clust)
  res <- matrix(NA,ncol=4,nrow=mx)
  colnames(res) <- c("clust","sum_1","sum_0","percent")
  for(i in 1:mx){
    id <- clust==i
    s1 <- sum(label[id]==1)
    s0 <- sum(label[id]==0)
    res[i,] <- c(i, s1, s0, s1/(s1+s0))
  }
  res[order(res[,"percent"],decreasing = T),]
}
```

But it seems to me that it is not written very much in R.’s style.
How would you write this function to make it run faster?

---

---

```
Unit: microseconds
                              expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq       max
             my_fu(cluster, label)   185.305   229.208   254.8142   251.1595   275.3915   382.584
           PGSA_fu(cluster, label)   909.419  1003.496  1272.7706  1133.7810  1287.4410 10025.276
         jay.sf_fu(cluster, label)  6152.120  6437.774  7196.9997  6787.0025  7515.1085 16177.966
 ThomasIsCoding_fu(cluster, label)  1167.705  1286.871  1438.5756  1385.2250  1488.1410  3471.757
  Jilber_Urbina_fu(cluster, label) 17980.839 19044.489 21186.8975 19953.9080 21575.1820 51005.578
 neval
   100
   100
   100
   100
   100
```

Comment: this seems like a great task for Code Review, as your code is working. You may want to open a question there instead

Comment: my point still stands

Comment: Just to be shure: You are aware of the `table` and `proportions` commands in R that are implemented in compiled code and thus will always be faster and are used by thousands of people for decades so there are likely no errors in there?

Answer (score 3):

You can try `table`

```
> table(cluster, label)
       label
cluster  0  1
      0 12  7
      1  9  9
      2  5  7
      3  8  7
      4  7  8
      5 11 10
```

or longer version with `data.frame` output

```
> d <- table(cluster, label)

> as.data.frame(cbind(d, freq = proportions(d, 1)[, "1"]))
   0  1      freq
0 12  7 0.3684211
1  9  9 0.5000000
2  5  7 0.5833333
3  8  7 0.4666667
4  7  8 0.5333333
5 11 10 0.4761905
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `xtabs`. Don't really understood your *percent* logic, though.

```
> as.data.frame.table(xtabs(~label + cluster, cbind(cluster, label))) |>
+   subset(cluster != 0) |>
+   reshape(timevar='label', idvar='cluster', direction='wide') |>
+   transform(freq=Freq.1/Freq.0)
   cluster Freq.0 Freq.1      freq
3        1      9      9 1.0000000
5        2      5      7 1.4000000
7        3      8      7 0.8750000
9        4      7      8 1.1428571
11       5     11     10 0.9090909
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(1)
cluster <- sample(0:5, 100, replace = T)
label <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(cluster, label) %>% 
  filter(cluster != 0) %>% 
  summarise(sum_1 = sum(label == 1),
            sum_0 = sum(label == 0),
            percent = sum_1/(sum_1 + sum_0)*100,
            .by = cluster) %>% 
  arrange(-percent)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
  cluster sum_1 sum_0 percent
    <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
1       2     7     5    58.3
2       4     8     7    53.3
3       1     9     9    50  
4       5    10    11    47.6
5       3     7     8    46.7
```

If you are concern about speed, you may want try dtplyr

```
library(dtplyr)
lazy_dt(tibble(cluster, label)) %>% 
  filter(cluster != 0) %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  summarise(sum_1 = sum(label == 1),
            sum_0 = sum(label == 0)) %>% 
  mutate(percent = sum_1/(sum_1 + sum_0)*100) %>% 
  arrange(-percent)

  cluster sum_1 sum_0 percent
    <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
1       2     7     5    58.3
2       4     8     7    53.3
3       1     9     9    50  
4       5    10    11    47.6
5       3     7     8    46.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `table` with a bit of extra manipulation:

```
metrics <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(cluster, label))
metrics$percent = metrics$`1` / (metrics$`1`+metrics$`0`)
metrics <- metrics[rownames(metrics) != "0",]
```

gives

```
   0  1   percent
1  9  9 0.5000000
2  5  7 0.5833333
3  8  7 0.4666667
4  7  8 0.5333333
5 11 10 0.4761905
```